# Simple example goes into endless loop

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I am trying to follow the example of creating a For Loop Container to run five (5) times in https://mindmajix.com/ssis/ssis-container

The dialog box containing "0" appears, but then the package goes into the running state and never stops. It does not seem that difficult. What might be wrong?

One part is better. I put the "Counter" variable into the ReadOnlyVariables. It works better when it is in the ReadWriteVariables.

However, now it will only display a value of zero (0) for the counter and will never stop looping.

```
For Loop Properties
InitExpression    @Counter = 0
EvalExpression    @Counter < 5
AssignExpression  @Counter = @Counter + 1
```

Comment: Use the tree view tab (the last tab) see what step it is up to and stuck on

Comment: what is your initExpression , EvalExpression and AsignExpression ?

Comment: Can you share the Foor Loop Editor InitExpression, EvalExpression, AssignExpression. What you have mentioned in your question was correct but something you have passed it incorrectly.

Comment: When you say "never stops", does it get stale or you keep getting pop ups with different/same counters? Do you have breakpoints set? Make sure that your looping box is the "For Loop" type.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your variable @Counter EvaluateExpression Property is **true** and Expression has value of **0**